# spring boot standalone error when build ClassNotFoundException DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot

### Context

Simple standalone application with below annotations in main class and datasoruce configuration, returning DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration ClassNotFoundException

### pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <!-- <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version> <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version> -->
        <!-- commons -->
        <commons.lang.version>2.5</commons.lang.version>
        <commons.io.version>2.4</commons.io.version>

        <c3po.version>0.9.1.2</c3po.version>
        <mysql.connector.java>5.1.31</mysql.connector.java>

        <!-- <velocity.version>1.7</velocity.version> -->
    </properties>



    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>




        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.192</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.java}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${c3po.version}</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

### Main class

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Component
@ComponentScan
```

### c3po datasource configuration

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public ComboPooledDataSource dataSource()  {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(maxSize);
        ....
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

with a dao class using this datasource ( it is not mentioned over here )

### Command run in console

mvn clean install spring-boot:run

### Error

```
[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationReadingVisitorUtils.convertClassValues(AnnotationReadingVisitorUtils.java:73)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor.java:134)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor.java:49)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:280)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:90)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:70)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:252)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:137)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:268)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:232)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:168)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
        at Main.main(Main.java:23)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 41 more
```

I have tried other approaches mentioned in the site, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 2):

Well I have tried various combinations and found out that I kept my Main class where the spring configuration is loaded, in default package and after moving it into the respective inner package ( say com.example ) , it worked.

I am sure this is not the correct reasoning, but what I am assuming per the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html), by keeping in base package, its scanning all the classes in the classpath.

Probably there is a better reasoning for this.